# Popup windows to select items on ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, popupwindow

I am new to the ASP.NET world and I need to do a popup to select some data.

The idea is that the user can select one or more options with a CheckBox. When he presses a button a popup appears with a list of options loaded from the database.

I don't know how to create a popup with those options and receive the selected options when the popup close. But I know how to do the option list from the database with a repeater.

Answer (score 0):

there is no such popup control in ASP.NET.

However there are numerous 3rd party plugins, which provide popup controls.

- [ajax tool kit model popup extender](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24087/Modal-Popup-Extender-Basics)
- [jquery built popups](http://www.jquery4u.com/windows/10-jquery-popup-window-image-slider-plugins/)

you can create your own. popup is nothing but a hidden container, which appears upon some action, and whose location and background is as per your choice.

create a popup like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="popup">
    </div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="popup" id="btnpopup" />
```

and css

```
.parent
{
    position:relative;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
.popup
{
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    position:relative;
    top:20%;
    left:20%;
    background-color:#DDDDDD;
    display:none;
}
```

and jQuery code

```
$('#btnpopup').click(function(){
   $('.popup').toggle(200);
});
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishmishra121/Q28XM/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `OnClientClick` of the button to open the popup. Depending on it being a normal browser popup or a jQuery dialog you have two general options:

- **Standard Popup**
  Standard popups open as if they are a separate page. When you click `OK` you may have to store the selection into the user's session if the data is needed on the page that triggered the popup, or store it directly in the database. If the former is the case, when you return to the page and submit it, the data from the popup will be available in the session to process.
- **jQuery Dialog** or particularly any js-triggered html dialog. You can show it with the corresponding js again in the `OnClientClick` function, and perform the selection. On the OK button click of the dialog almost nothing is needed (except hiding it). Since the dialog input controls are part of the page, they will be posted on submit and be process-able on the server.

That's basically all you need to do, but some more reading on the topic won't hurt. Good luck.